# angular service available at configuration phase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-routing

I want to move some of the repetitive logic out in a reusable service, which *must be available in a config phase*. And possibly have access to `$xxxProvider` dependency injections too. Is such thing possible? Can one do this with factory/provider/service/constant ?

To be specific, when I define my routes with `ui-router`, I noticed that routes for CRUD are all the same, except for the names of the resources. So i'd like to move this logic of configuring a CRUD route somewhere to make route definitions more DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing your service provider in the config block, this should work just fine:

```
app.service('myService', function (/* dependencies */) {
  // service stuff..

  return this; 
});

app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('myService', function ($delegate) {
    // $delegate refers to 'myService'. 
    // You can modify its behaviour and what not in here.

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

I'm not crystal clear on what you are looking for, but this 'just works'.

Do note, that the service registration needs to come before the `config` block if they reside in the same file. A way to overcome this, would be to extract your service into a separate module and inject it as a dependency to your main module. Something like this:

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('serviceModule', []);

serviceModule.service('myService', function () {});

var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['serviceModule']);

mainModule.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('myService', function ($delegate) {});
});
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/pasiquju/2/edit

### Edit

I've now put together a **rough** example of how you could do the following:

1. Register your own custom provider constructor, that returns an object.
2. Inject another `provider` into your own provider, passing through functionality from one constructor to another.
3. Register a secondary service, that gets injected into the provider constructor.
4. Pass some more functionality from the `app.config` block to your provider constructor.
5. Inject the instance returned by the constructor into a controller.
6. Output the end data from the instance returned by the constructor, with args.

This should cover the needs specified:

- Prone to DI, from `providers`.
- Prone to DI, from services.
- Available during config phase.

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/jenumobi/2/edit

And [here's the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for the `provider` shorthand methods, and how they differ. As you can clearly see, the `provider` core function is the one with the most options available to it - but also the hardest to work with, for obvious reasons.

I hope that will do enough for you, and give you some sort of idea on how to create your own `$stateProvider` extension! I've done my best to document the code in the JsBin to make it easier to understand just how it all ties together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Please take a look at this fiddle to maybe have more Idea of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsbin.com/hubayefi/1/edit


As you can see `constant` is available at config phase, but I doesn't allow dependency injections into it, which limits the stuff I can do inside it. I'm looking for an equivalent to `constant`, but with DI. Maybe that's just stupid though :(

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that is not possible with value/constant.`value` can recieve DI and be modified in a decorator, but it is not available during config. `constant` is available during config, but cannot recieve DI or be modified by a decorator. There is no middleground that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you create your own `provider` however, then I suppose you could have access to it during config phase, and apply DI to it with a decorator. Never done that myself though.

Comment: And just now I realise that you **do** have access to other providers when declaring your own provider. I'll whip up a JsBin when I get home. Won't be long.

Comment: You are most welcome. It's a ton of fun to experiment with some more elaborate tasks in angular. See my updated answer for a solution that *should* fit your needs.